# How can statistics for all active ROS Topics be obtained?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to display statistics for all active ROS topics in a system?  By statistics I mean bandwidth usage, publishing rate, number of messages dropped, etc.  I looked at "rostopic bw" and "rostopic hz" but they only display information for one topic at a time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61093/how-can-statistics-for-all-active-ros-topics-be-obtained?/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-19**:
Seems generally useful. If there is not already a solution, you can probably fork a copy of rostopic and modify it to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since ROS Indigo node statistics are available via:

`rosparam set enable_statistics true` (see http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics)

A nice framework including rqt plugins is available on https://github.com/ROS-PSE/arni

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3